# Cardview not allowing child views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-cardview

Anyone know why I would not be allowed to put any child views in a card view?

Lint (i think) is throwing a fit when I try to fill my cardview with content.

[image: http://imgur.com/ODhDFiZ]

Comment: Tried running the code? Because this might be an wrong warning message from android studio

Comment: Thanks, yes. It does run, but (a) i just wanted to make sure I was not missing anything obvious, and (b) the supposed error disables autocomplete, so it is a small hindrance to use as such. also, the padding does not work which is a trouble as well.

Comment: kindly upvote the comment

Comment: That is a bug in android studi for now just type it manually, tools team will fix that in next releases

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but I've had this same problem and the fix seems to be to add this line in the build.gradle file, then sync the project. This way Gradle/Android Studio knows what CardView is and how to provide hints:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.+'
```